# NodeJS, mysql connection to localhost. Why is my mysql object not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-connector

I am trying to use mysql with "mysql = require('mysql')" in my Nodejs server web application. Now when I try to use the mysql object (that i required with the above require command) it gives me an error saying:

message "mysql is not defined"

What am I doing wrong. Code belov. Thanks in advance for all the help <3 much love.

I tried using an mysql object (that i required) to create a connection object. I didnt expect the mysql object to be undefined. Whats wrong?

`

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

class Model {
  connection;

  constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '3306',
      user: 'creativepages',
      password: 'creativepages',
      database: 'main'
    });
  }

  execute(sqlquery) {

    this.connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return err;
      } else {
        this.connection.query(sqlquery, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return false;
          }
        });

        this.connection.end(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return err;
          }
        });

        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

`

Comment: Okay, so I added a this. in front of mysql.createConnection and now it gives me the following followup error:

"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'escape')"

Comment: if I use Model.mysql.createConnection it gives me the same error. Hm

Comment: `mysql` becomes to an own property of the instance, you refer it with `this.mysql` in the methods. I'd recommend to create it to the class as a [static property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), though.

Comment: okay i am not following you all the way. what would that mean in case of code changes?

Make the property from mysql to static msql = require('mysql');? 
and then use Model.mysql to access?

Comment: Alternatively to making it a static property of the class as Teemu suggested, you can require it outside of this class in the same file using `const mysql = require('mysql')` you can then just reference `mysql` inside the class to use it. JavaScript require is a bit equivalent to import in other languages

Comment: @RogerSchneiter Yes, exactly like that. I wouldn't break the encapsulation using the structure rowan-vr has suggested.

Comment: Besides the require, your execute method shouldn't be static as it references the connection. To use this it needs the instance, which static doesn't have

Comment: @rowan-vr hey thanks for the reply.  I changed it so that the mysql const with the require is outside of the class. then i try to use it to initalize my connection property, still doesnt work. I am lost...

This is how it is now:

const mysql = require('mysql')

class Model {
  connection;

  constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '3306',
      user: 'creativepages',
      password: 'creativepages',
      database: 'main'
    });
  }

  execute(sqlquery) {

    this.connection.connect(function(err) {

Comment: i updated the code in the post to what it is now. Still this error:

Comment: message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'escape')"

Comment: Did you possibly forget a required parameter in one of the functions? And which of the functions are you executing where this error occurs?